# Erro no libpython, instalando Trac, rodando com o apache 2.4

Tags: python, apache, openldap

Estou instalando [Trac](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall) com o Apche2.4 mod_python, mais quando inicio o serviço aparece o seguinte erro:

```
[:error] [pid 7937:tid 140094741256064] python_init: Python version mismatch, expected '2.7.5+', found '2.7.9'.
[:error] [pid 7937:tid 140094741256064] python_init: Python executable found '/usr/bin/python'.
[:error] [pid 7937:tid 140094741256064] python_init: Python path being used '/usr/lib/python2.7/:/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload'.
```

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim -a solução é não usar mod_python -

De acordo com a documentação do Trac - https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall - mod_python seria uma das opções - no entanto o desenvolvimento do mod_python parou há mais de 5 anos, e há inclusive mais de uma carta aberta de seu mantenedor e desenvolvedor principal pedindo para que ele *não* *seja* mais usado ( http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/06/modpython-project-is-now-officially.html ) - 
ele é complicado, não é mais mantido, e teve que criar várias versões da "roda" num tempo em que não havia um padrão para se conectar aplicações Python a servidores WEB.

Depois do Mod Python foi criada a especificação WSGI que padroniza essa interação - e o TRAC, apesar de antigo e estar evoluindo apenas lentamente, suporta WSGI - de acordo com a documentação acima. Então, se você for realmente usar Apache, use-o com mod_wsgi, não com mod_python

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, esclareceu varias coisas.